# ROS Answers SE migration: PHP+ROSTOPIC

Tags: ros, python, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a question to all of you.
For example, I have simple publisher and subscriber. The topic name "/test". I want click button on my PHP website and in the case when I will do this the data on a topic will change.
If I want to publish some data from command line, such as:

```
rostopic pub -1 /test std_msgs/Int32 10000
```

It works.

The problem is:

Can I make the next situation on my PHP file

```
<?php
exec("rostopic pub -1 /test std_msgs/Int32 10000")
?>
```

Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243665/php+rostopic/) by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be possible. Make sure your web server (or PHP interpreter) has the proper environment setup when it tries to invoke `rostopic` (ie: equivalent of `source setup.bash`).

Alternative (and I think preferred): use [rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) and use the JSON interface from your PHP script.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on 2016-09-14**:
Thank you for your answer.
Are you mean the next way:

```
exec("source /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash && rostopic pub -1 /test std_msgs/Int32 10000")
```

or

```
exec("source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash && /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rostopic pub -1 /test std_msgs/Int32 10000")
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-14**:
That depends: if all you want is `rostopic` and `std_msgs`, then you only need to source the base distribution. If you need custom messages and / or a custom node, then I think you'd need to source your workspace.

**Comment by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on 2016-09-14**:
I need a custom node with std_msgs. I tried both of the ways but still does not work. What can be the problem?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-14**:
I don't know. What does `exec(..)` return? Any error status/message? What "doesn't work" exactly?